# Use servlet to check if form field exist?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a JSP and servlet where the JSP contains a multi-level/multi-step form. The servlet pulls parameters from the JSP, passes it to the controller and to the DB. This is all functioning but I was wondering how I can go about checking if say a text box, drop down, or really any input field exist on the JSP.

Currently my servlet just checks the parameters for a null or empty field and does other things, that are tangent to my need here. For example though, I have a piece of javascript that allows you add additional name field to the jsp, with a max of 5. What I need to do on the servlet is first check to see if that name field exist and if it does, check the parameter from it, though I'm not entirely sure how to do this.

I tried assigning a name parameter to the text fields and wanted to use the servlet to check if this name exist but what I get the parameter, I get a servlet error. Can someone suggest a way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share some of your code.

Comment: You're already doing it. If the named field is absent or empty you will get a null when you get it as a parameter value. These are not different things.